# Unknown encoded string

Tags: base64, url-encoding

Do you have any tip on how to decode this string (encode my string to this format)? Seems to be something like base64 combined with...

```
n69k0J0xLSEqh0IFG2ZGgeZwLZ0SuiSe:sO6uELP0yW:S17zihfs6qpW20E7R7U2NTZsXzW1YKYIoEUqBXGvygY5CkKolsoh
```

I hope original string **maybe** sth like this:

```
ttInd=0&i=750&s1=1234&s2=4321
```

Comment: It is definitely not base64. Where is this data coming from exactly? That might give a clue as to what type of encoding(s) are supported by that format/protocol.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't say **today**. I can only present another strings like these:

`dCqkxyICL8vSuMr8H5ORzQ--` => `key=8680001&amp;ttInd=5297`

`3NYuZuHJIRoqCAQ0LDD:2Q--` => `key=2830001&amp;ttInd=2755`

`ziqhDiw5xVEVivOwpfR.RQ--` => `key=4620001&amp;ttInd=2871`

Comment: Without any context, how do you expect people to answer? There are many different data-to-text encoding algorithms.

Comment: There are base64 variants for URLs and identifiers, but the values you show do not match those algorithms.  So whatever the site is using, it is likely either a custom algorithm, or a rare variant of an existing algorithm. Have you thought about maybe contacting the site admin and ask?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that `--` represents padding, and the fact that the encoded data can have `:` and `.` characters in it, one might first jump to the conclusion that it could be a modified base64 variant. But the length of the encoded data is <= the length of the input data (depending on whether `&amp;` really is `&amp;` or is actually `&` before encoding), so it can't be based on base64, which always produces encoded data that is longer than the input data.  So there is either a simple replacement algorithm in play, or some amount of bit compression is being used.  Either way, without more context about what kind of format/protocol this encoded data is actually being used in, there is simply no way to answer this question as-is.  There are simply too many data-to-text encoding algorithms used in the real world to narrow this down by trial-an-error.